# CURL Rest API via Proxy

Tags: linux, api, curl, servicenow

I want to get data from ServiceNow via a CURL in Putty via a Proxyserver (Plan is to implement it to a PySpark script later on) and then save the data onto the server.

My Command looks like this:

```
curl -x <proxyadress:port> -U proxyuser:proxypassword -u '<apiuser:apipassword>' -d status="message" "https:/apiadress" -H 'Accept: application/json'
```

I get the error message:

```
 {"error":{"message":"Invalid content-type. Supported request media types for this service are: [application/json, application/xml, text/xml]","detail":null},"status":"failure"}
```

A few days ago I was able to have the data printed into the log but didn't manage to replicate the command ... what's wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: call me crazy but I would guess on you using an invalid content-type... Maybe set one of the ones it lists as acceptable?

Comment: but I did do that right? I mean application/json is listed ... or am I using the -H at the wrong place?

Comment: You added an `Accept:` header, yes, the error seems to say it wants the `Content-type:` (as well?)

Comment: While it makes no sense, -H "Content-Type: json/application" may be correct.  I would think it should be Accept too. Try Content-Type and try using both Accept and Content-Type.   https://reqbin.com/req/c-ea0d5rlb/curl-send-header-example